# how to build logical representation from dependency tree

Tags: lambda-calculus, python

I'm trying to build logical representation from dependency tree with python. 
i created the tree with stanford parser. 
How can I derive logical presentation from it using Lambda-calculus?

Comment: What sort of dependency tree do you have? The Stanford parser can make a few different types. An example would help a lot here.

Comment: It's giving me this output for the sentence : who is the leader of Ukraine ?                                                                                   [(('who', 'WP'), 'cop', ('is', 'VBZ')),
 (('who', 'WP'), 'nsubj', ('leader', 'NN')),
 (('leader', 'NN'), 'det', ('the', 'DT')),
 (('leader', 'NN'), 'nmod', ('Ukraine', 'NNP')),
 (('Ukraine', 'NNP'), 'case', ('of', 'IN'))]

Comment: I probably should get something like { y |  < Ukraine, president, y> }